# Mongoose - Error on .save() on PUT request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a User model where I put the `password` field as required. The problem is that when I try to update a User without sending a `password`, an error is raised because it says the `password` is required.

How do I set the `password` to required when creating, but not on updating? Extending this, how do I create an endpoint that can receive from 1 to 4 attributes on the request?

**PUT endpoint**

```
exports.putUsuario = function(req, res) {
    Usuario.findById(req.user._id, function(err, usuario) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        if (usuario){
        // Update the existing beer quantity
        usuario.password = req.body.password;
        usuario.nome = req.body.nome;
        usuario.sexo = req.body.sexo;
        usuario.idade = req.body.idade;

        // Save the beer and check for errors
        usuario.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(usuario);
        });
      }
      else {
        res.json(usuario);
      }
    });
};
```

**Error returned to Postman**

```
{
  "errors": {
    "password": {
      "message": "Path `password` is required.",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "properties": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
        "path": "password"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "password"
    }
  },
  "message": "Usuario validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can disable validation on a "per-save" basis: it's either enabled for all `save()` (and `create()`) operations, or it's not (in which case you can validate manually, if you want). Perhaps it's worth looking into [`findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate), for which validation is _disabled_ by default.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @robertklep. Changing to `findByIdAndUpdate` fixed this error. But now this is not running through the `Model.pre('save', function())` middleware.

Comment: Ah yes, that won't work. But there's a `findOneAndUpdate` hook that will get called, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting your password each time even if it's empty/undefined.

Test if the request body has a password before setting it:

```
if (req.body.password) {
    usuario.password = req.body.password;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the easy fix. Tried the `findByIdAndUpdate` suggested by @robertklep, but it was requesting me to change my middleware to hash modified passwords.

Comment: No problem. Glad this helped.

Comment: I mistakenly assumed that when using `save()`, a password had to be present. But because the document already exists, it's internally handled as an update. +1!